# copy form using google api and change linkedSheetId

Tags: google-sheets, google-api

After creating a copy of a google form is it possible to change `linkedSheetId` for a google form using google apis to make the form store the results in an arbitrary sheet ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not. According to the official documentation ([here](https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1/forms#Form)) and some support requests ([here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/231701346)). I believe this is intentional, in order to allow you to develop your own custom API with Google Sheet API. Even if it is very inconvenient.